# Memory Utilization GWT application

Tags: performance, gwt, memory

We are trying to load test GWT Application (2.0.4) where all the widgets are loading on a single page and it makes nearly 20 rpc calls while loading the page.

Server: JBoss 5 and we are monitoring the heap memory using JConsole.

During the load test we notice that the heap memory increases to max even for min number of  users. However the memory is getting reclaimed once gc is triggered.

Could anyone explain Why the memory utilization (heap memory) is so high for GWT application on server  even for small number of users?

We are using Hibernate + Spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

1) It would help to reduce the number of GWT RPC calls on application screen launch by combining the data they fetch. Multiple RPC calls on load tend to block up lot of resource on browser and on server.

2) Analyze whether you need all the data your RPC calls are fetching first up.

3) The heap space usage varies depending on server side technology you are using Hibernate, Dozer, Gilead, lazy/cache loading etc.

4) Code Splitting  and Fragment Merge help you reduce your app javascript which you load first up.

I am guessing you are using Dozer to copy hibernate entities to DTO/beans of client side. Try playing around with hibernate C3P0 connection pool settings.